# Invalid query key thrown because of JPQL statement in eclipselink 2.5.2 but works in 2.3.2

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I have the following JQPL query:

```
SELECT e FROM Emp e WHERE SIZE(e.companyBean.emps) > 0
```

The problem is that it didn't work on eclipselink 2.5.2, when I tried it on 2.3.2 it worked successfully

I thought that there maybe some changes in JPA that disallow this path navigation but couldn't find anything on the web.

So is there something wrong about this query or changes in eclipselink that may be the cause of this exception ??

Thanks

The whole maven project: https://github.com/mohamedkomalo/jpa2-eclipselink/

The Emp entity: https://github.com/mohamedkomalo/jpa2-eclipselink/blob/master/src/main/java/model/Emp.java

The Company entity: https://github.com/mohamedkomalo/jpa2-eclipselink/blob/master/src/main/java/model/Company.java

The exception

```
Exception in thread "main" Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-6015] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: Invalid query key [
Query Key emps
   Base model.Emp{DatabaseTable(t0)=DatabaseTable(emp)}] in expression.
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="Emp.findEmployeesInBigCompanies" referenceClass=Emp jpql="SELECT e FROM Emp e WHERE SIZE(e.companyBean.emps) > 0")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.invalidQueryKeyInExpression(QueryException.java:697)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.ObjectExpression.getDescriptor(ObjectExpression.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.SubSelectExpression.normalizeSubSelect(SubSelectExpression.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.ExpressionNormalizer.normalizeSubSelects(ExpressionNormalizer.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.SQLSelectStatement.normalize(SQLSelectStatement.java:1534)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.buildNormalSelectStatement(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:549)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.prepareSelectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:1720)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.prepareSelectAllRows(ReadAllQuery.java:813)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.prepare(ReadAllQuery.java:744)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:661)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.checkPrepare(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:901)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:613)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getDatabaseQueryInternal(QueryImpl.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createNamedQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1124)
    at practicies.Day2.runPractice3(Day2.java:58)
    at practicies.Day2.main(Day2.java:22)
```

Comment: I'm testing `SIZE` with EclipseLink 2.5.0 and it is working like a charm. Would you mind posting `Company` entity definition along with relationship to `empCollection`?

Comment: @zbigniewTomczak not at all, I have posted the Company entity ... I can upload the whole project as it is a practice project for me to try JPA

Comment: Looks like a bug in creating a sub query over the companyBean relationship, though I don't know why it would have broken in 2.5.  What happens if you specify the join outside of the size function?  ie: "SELECT e FROM Emp e join e.companyBean companyBean WHERE SIZE(companyBean.emps) > 0"

Comment: @Chris can you post your comment as an answer so that I can mark it as the accepted answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug in creating a subquery over the `companyBean` relationship. A workaround might be to specify the join outside of the `SIZE` function, i.e. `SELECT e FROM Emp e join e.companyBean companyBean WHERE SIZE(companyBean.emps) > 0`.

Answer (score 0):

`Company` doesn't have field named `empCollection`. Maybe you changed the `Company` implementation in the meantime and forgot to update Named query? If you update the query to

```
SELECT e FROM Emp e WHERE SIZE(e.company.emps) > 100
```

is should work.

I also see you don't have correct relationship between `Emp` and `Company`. `mappedBy="companyBean"` does not point correctly to a field in Emp.

Comment: Sorry I have added the query and Company entity and exception info from a project and the Emp entity from another project, this is my bad, I was trying another IDE and making changes, that's why I included other project files by mistake ... I have uploaded the whole project on github and provided links to the correct entity classes, in maven when I use eclipselink to 2.3.2, the project runs successfully, when I change it to eclipselink 2.5.2 the exception occurs